# The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The service is configured to not accept any remote shell requests

Tags: iis, server, windows-server-2019

We have Windows Server 2019 and I am trying to enable IIS feature on it but getting this error '*The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The service is configured to not accept any remote shell requests.*'.

I have searched google a lot and followed the steps and enabled **AllowRemoteShellAccess** to `true`, but still getting the same error.

I am not sure is there any other step that needs to be done before that since I do not have a server side background.

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

CIS Bench marks are more advanced and secure set of instructions to tighten the security of Microsoft Windows Infrastructure. These Bench marks provide instructions to secure every aspect of operating systems (Windows Linux) as well as leading web servers. If you follow these CIS bench marks particularly for Windows Server 2016 or 2019 you might be blocking many items required for the administrator to perform routine jobs.

[image]

There is a group policy object which needs to be amended to resolve this issue. The setting can be located in the following group policy path to resolve the issue of “The ws-management service cannot process the request”:
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Remote Shell > Allow Remote Shell Access. ***Once you are done with the disabling of this Group Policy Object, don’t forget to run the command gpupdate /force.***

Comment: Once you are done with the disabling of this Group Policy Object, don’t forget to run the command `gpupdate /force` in an elevated CMD

Comment: Is there any reason why I need to allow remote shell access to configure a local server non-remotely? Disabling that GPO sounds like bad security practice yet all the internet is basically telling me to disable security...

Comment: Even after running gpupdate /force this change didn't seem to have any effect but a reboot did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Enabling this policy didn't work for me either.  Here's what worked for me:

1. See if there are any IP addresses listed in iplisten by issuing the command "netsh http show iplisten".
2. If there are, delete those by issuing the command "netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=".
3. Now try installing IIS and it should be successful.
4. Re-add those IP addresses back by issuing the command "netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=".

I hope this works for you.